# Carbide does not include debugging info for some files

Tags: eclipse, gcc, symbian, s60, carbide

In Carbide 2.0.2, if I set active configuration to be "Phone Debug GCCE", build the project, go to Debug perspective, choose "Executables" tab, and select the executable file, Source File Name/Location window will list all the files I am able to use while debugging.

The problem is that the list does not contain all files from the project, even though their code is successfully linked and executed on a device. As a consequence of the issue, I am not able to set break points in these files.

What is the catch and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the version of GCCE that is used by default with Symbian. It has a number of bugs with debug information, including sometimes missing line information for some files.

The alternatives are (a) the commercial RVCT compiler, or (b) follow the in-progress work to move to a newer GCCE compiler. A good start for that is here:
http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/The_GCCE_toolchain_initiative

Comment: The trick is that this issue does not have same result/impact on every single computer, so some secret setting/clean up/fine tuning, whatever, might do magic. At least, I hope so.